# How can I change the horizontal spacing in a figure environment?

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats

I want to put two figures, one at the top and one at the bottom, into one figure environment. I only want one common label and caption. 
How can I adjust the horizontal positioning of each of the figures?

I tried

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \hspace{10pt}\includegraphics[width=12cm]{a.eps}\\[20pt]
  \hspace{20pt}\includegraphics[width=12cm]{b.eps}\\
  \caption{....}
  \label{...}
\end{figure}
```

but it fails.

Comment: delete the `\\ ` and put a blank line between then normally people use `\centering` at the start but if you want to offset each "by hand" use `hspace*{10pt}` with a `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the `\\` and put a blank line between then normally people use

```
\centering
```

at the start but if you want to offset each "by hand" use `\hspace*{10pt}` with a `*`.

Note that there is nothing specific to images or the `figure` environment here, the same would be true if you wanted to position two words on the main page content.